# Gridview separate scrolling columns

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

Is there any way to achieve the possibility to scroll just a specific column in a Gridview?

There is another Question, basicly about the same topic.
The answer there was, to just take two Gridviews. 
( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776578/scroll-specific-column-inside-gridview-gridlayout )

Since I want to use a ItemTouchHelper for Drag and Drop support, i can only use one recyclerview with one Gridview but still want to be able to scroll single columns.

I am thankful for any help and suggestions!